# Arguments in js function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 3 columns that show cards back, [like this](http://www.caragails.com/cg-images/cards/desjgn/all_backs.jpg), so when a I press on card, an alert show me his number, but I don't know how show the number, I tried with href and onClick but I haven't success

The html

```
<table id="gallery">
</table>

<script>generateTable3col();</script>
```

The js

```
function generateTable3col(){
    var cards = [5,1,8,3,2,4,6];

    var rows = cards.length/3;
    var columns = 3;
    var rowNode, columnNode, link, img;
    var table = document.getElementById("gallery")
    var image = "backcard.png"

    for (var r=0;r<rows;r++){
        rowNode = document.createElement("tr");
        rowNode.style = "width:33%;";
        table.appendChild(rowNode);

        for(var c=0;c<columns; c++){
            columnNode =document.createElement("td");
            columnNode = table.appendChild(columnNode);

            link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("hideNumber", cards[1*r+c]);

            //here I don't know how do
            link.href = "javascript:showCard(this)" //this is window object
            link.onclick = showCard(this); //execute when call the loop not when click

            img = document.createElement("img"); 
            img.style = "width: 100%;"
            img.src = image;

            link.appendChild(img);

            columnNode.appendChild(link);

        }
    }
}

//How?
function showCard(element){
    alert("card is: " + element.getAttribute("hideNumber")); //element is object window, not <a> element
}
```

Comment: `link.onclik` — you have a typo here. Should be `link.onclick`

Comment: not I have this well

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, could you improve the wording of the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
link.onclick = showCard(this);
```

Use this:

```
link.onclick = function() { showCard(this); };
```

The difference here is that in the first case, `showCard(this);` is executed right away. While in the second case, you're assigning a function to `onclick` that will only get executed once the click occurs.